# Flutter : PopUp Form value showing null

Tags: flutter, authentication, popup, textformfield

Iam new to flutter.
In my project I need to show a popup when i load my page. So i used WidgetsBindingin initstate().
My code is working fine for showing popup on pageload, but in that popup,there is a textfield to enter mobile number after submitting i need to get that phone number but it not showing the value. While compiling it showing null value.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
super.initState();

// _fetchSessionAndNavigate();
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
  await showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => new AlertDialog(
      content: Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            right: -40.0,
            top: -40.0,
            child: InkResponse(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: CircleAvatar(
                child: Icon(Icons.close),
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    obscureText: true,
                    autofocus: false,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter Mobile Number',
                        icon: new Icon(
                          Icons.phone_iphone,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        )),
                    validator: (value) => value.isEmpty
                        ? 'Phone Number can\'t be empty'
                        : null,
                    onSaved: (value) => phoneNumber = value.trim();
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Register Your Device"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        //_formKey.currentState.save();
                        Print (_phoneNumber); //NEED TO GET ENTERED VALUE HERE
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
});
```

}

Comment: I got  result : .I forget to add  TextEditingController txt1  = TextEditingController();and i update my code by adding ----" controller: txt1"

Comment: Your code is working fine, except that you need to uncomment this line: `_formKey.currentState.save()` and change `Print(_phoneNumber)` to `print(phoneNumber)`. Also, check if you have defined `phoneNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the await keyword from in front of the function and call it like this:

```
showDialog({the dialog}).then((dialogResult){
   setState((){
      yourLocalVariable = dialogResult;
   });
});
```